# Authorize.Net on magento 1.9.2

Tags: ce-1.9.2.0, authorize.net

Authorize.net on magento .1.9.2 is not working with Test mode set to NO. It is giving Gate way error(Gateway error: This transaction has been declined. Response code 103). When Test mode is Yes . It is accepting transactions.
I don't know what is wrong with it. I tried new trasaction key, cleared cache , reindexed.

***Can anyone please help me.***

Comment: It's look like your transaction key is invalid for live mode. you will need to recheck it.

Comment: Same transaction key working on other platform and it is accepting all transactions.

Comment: And what about API Login ID and Merchant's Email? Is it also same as other platform?

Comment: Also check your payment method settings by changing Current Configuration Scope to website and store.

Comment: yes, It has same login id and merchant's email

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing in the sandbox, you should not set your gateway to test mode nor should you include testmode=true in your request.  If you do, the gateway will only check if the credentials are correct and return OK.  It will not attempt to process a transaction.

You can read more about error 103 here: http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/responseCodes.html?code=103

Comment: If I set Test mode to false, It is throwing Gateway error with response code 103.